# Create dashed lines in QGIS that will export as dashed in a GeoJSON file

Tags: qgis, line, display

I have a project that has several lines in QGIS. I know how to make them display as dashed in QGIS, but I need to make them into actual dashed lines instead of just displaying them as dashed because the software I'm going to end up displaying this in doesn't support any sort of style at all, just reading raw GeoJSON and displaying it. Thus, for any dashed line it needs to be converted to a series of smaller lines with actual breaks in between.

Is there an automated method for doing this in QGIS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Create evenly spaced points along the geometry with **Points along geometry**
2. **Buffer** them with the gap distance you want between the dashes
3. **Difference** the start line with the buffers:

[image]